# How show/hide links in another component?

Tags: angular

I have the following structure of main component `app.component` in Angular:

```
<div class="links">
    <div class="link_1"></div>
    <div class="link_2"></div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

So in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` different components are substituted.

How to hide `<div class="link_1"></div>` if there is component inside `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`as instance `EventComponent`?

And how to show `<div class="link_2"></div>` if it is another component, no matter which. I am wondering how to show/hide menu elements above depend current component below.

I don't want to create variable in each component as `public show = true;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try including the router in your component with the router outlet and look for the path corresponding with the link selected, e.g.

```
constructor(private _router: Router ) {}

get currentUrl() { return this._router.url; }
```

then in your template

```
<div *ngIf="currentUrl !== 'someUrl'" class="link_1"></div>
```

Comment: Is it good practice or better use global service? Does Angular provide information about which component is current in use?

Comment: might just be personal preference, but you could definitely use a service too; just set a property in the service for which route is currently activated by setting it in each component you want to track, then read that value in the container component to change which links are active.   often just looking at the route is simpler, since it does not require adding a new service or any code to the route components, and depending on what you need to track it will keep your codebase simpler

Comment: Problem is that I have one component with menu items inside main component. Also it can be some nested component on the same page. depending on which is active I need show/hide menu items in another component.

Comment: if you can't determine which component is active by looking at the route, then yes, you'll need to create a service and inject it into every component which can affect that show/hide decision to update.  you may also need to use ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy to make sure your service variables are up to date when components load and unload

Comment: How compare with mark like: `*ngIf="currentUrl !== 'list/{id}'" class="link_1"`

Comment: `*ngIf="!currentUrl.match(/^list\/\d+$/)" class="link_1"`